# How can I set vsftpd user-specific access?

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, chroot, vsftpd

I'm using vsftpd (on 14.04) and I want to set user-specific access:
- admin has full access to home folder of all users
- standard user (everyone from group "users") has permission only for his home folder and there he has full access, he hasn't any access to home folder of other users
- admin home dir (or at least its content) is invisible for standard users

How can I set these rules?
Thanks for any advice

Comment: The config file under the /etc holds all the settings you'd ever need to configure vsftpd daemon. visit the **/etc/vsftpd.conf** for details

Comment: Read this [page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/vsftpd.conf.5.html) for more info